# hoe getopt() deals with char type

Tags: getopt

I have a question about the getopt function, as the following code shows, the type of "ch" is "int",but in the switch clause, it is regarded as "char" .. I am confused why?

Thansk!!

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
extern int optind;
extern char * optarg;
int ch;
char * format = "f:hnBm:";

// Default makefile name will be Makefile
char szMakefile[64] = "Makefile";
char szTarget[64];
char szLog[64];

while((ch = getopt(argc, argv, format)) != -1) 
{
    switch(ch) 
    {
        case 'f':
            strcpy(szMakefile, strdup(optarg));
            break;
        case 'n':
            break;
        case 'B':
            break;
        case 'm':   

            strcpy(szLog, strdup(optarg));
            break;
        case 'h':
        default:
            show_error_message(argv[0]);
            exit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, a `char` is really just an integer of a certain size and an `int` can be implicitly converted into one, so it works transparently.

Comment: But when I printf ("%d",ch),it gives me a value of 1 no matter I type 'f','B'or'm'...seems like there is no difference . Do you know why

Comment: I ran the exact code in your question with that `printf` added just at the beginning of the loop and saw different numbers. Did you change something in your code when you pasted it ...?

Answer (score 0):

When you compare a char and an int in C (such as in your switch statement), the compiler will automatically cast the char to type int. So in your switch statement above, the 'f' is cast automatically to 102, which is the numerical value that corresponds to ASCII 'f'. So, in the switch statement in your code, the 'ch' is not really regarded as a char. Rather, the characters in the case statements are all cast to be int so they match the type of "ch"

Comment: But when I printf ("%d",ch),it gives me a value of 1 no matter I type 'f','B'or'm'...seems like there is no differnce